# DATE FORMAT :DB2 _ SQL

Tags: sql, db2

I have date format (TIMESTAMP) like 2018-03-26-08.30.00.000000  and i want to get it as 2018-03-26-08 how i can do it in sql in DB2(just i want year-month-day-hour )'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read DB2's manual:
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/12?topic=sf-char

Using that docu:

1. I need to convert the non-standard in-format with a dash between day and hour, and dots as hour/minute and minute/second separators to a timestamp, using `TO_TIMESTAMP()`.
2. From the obtained timestamp, I can use `TO_CHAR()` with a format string to give me back a string with the format I desire.

```
WITH
indata(ts) AS (
  SELECT 
    TO_TIMESTAMP(
     '2018-03-26-08.30.00.000000','YYYY-MM-DD-HH24.MI.SS.US'
    ) 
  FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
)
SELECT TO_CHAR(ts,'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24') AS new_format FROM indata;
  new_format    
---------------
 2018-03-26-08
```

Answer (score 0):

```
VARCHAR_FORMAT(<timestamp>, '<desired format>')
```

So:

```
SELECT VARCHAR_FORMAT(CURRENT TIMESTAMP, 'YYYY-MM-DD-hh24')
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```